# Suggestion for best standard API protocol to be used in web services in a javaEE server?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

We have not used Webservices yet(in fact we are new to JavaEE infrastructure), I am looking at JAX-WS as the webservice format, but I am not sure if there are still newly emerge better solutions out there that we may try instead. We can choose which standards we wanted to use, and clients that will be using the webservices will in a way also used that standard.

Any idea is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JAX-WS is good and mature. So stick with it, if you need SOAP services.
If you don't need the rigidness of SOAP, you can use RESTful services. JAX-RS is the standard for that.

Btw, it is no longer called "j2ee". It's JavaEE now.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer and the correction. I have a follow-up question though. I am aware that JAX-WS is naturally called from some other java-ee server. I have seen(though I am not so sure it's what it is) there's a SOAP wrapper in PHP invoking a JAX-WS. If it is possible, then I assume SOAP can also be invoked in a javascript in a browser(client side).

Comment: yes, SOAP can be invoked by any language. That's why it is a standard.